# How to unfold or close content in html/JS - always assigned to different id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating a website for learning reasons. Right now I am trying to make a course overview realized in tables. For each course I want to give a description, but only if the viewer wants it. So in the beginning its closed and if you click a + or something it opens (like a spoiler). And this for multiple table rows.

It looks like this now:

HTML:

```
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Date</td>
    <td>Place</td>
    <td>Time</td>
    <td>$</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>
        <div id="open" onclick="open('course1')">+</div>
    </td>
    <td colspan="4">
        <div id="course1" style="display:none;">
            Here is the text

            <div id="close" onclick="close('course1')"><br/>X</div>

        </div>

    </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

JS:

```
<script>
            function open(id) {
                document.getElementById(id).style.display='block';
                document.getElementById('open').style.display='none';
                document.getElementById('close').style.display='block';
            }
            function close(id) {
                document.getElementById(id).style.display='none';
                document.getElementById('open').style.display='block';
                document.getElementById('close').style.display='none'
            }
        </script>
```

CSS:

```
    #open {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    }

    #close {
        cursor: pointer;
    }
```

The code works fine, if I tell in the JS section the "getElementById" a fixed id. But I want to have this multiple times. But this does not work. So I want to tell the JS always the needed id.

Does somebody know, how I can provide the actuall id for the function?

I hope I ask the right questions and provide it the right way.
English is not my mother tounge so forgive me for mistakes.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple example. Notice I've added the `id` of the div you want to expand into the link to open it using a `data` attribute:

```
<table>
  <tr>
      <td>
          <div id="open" class="opener" data-toopen="course1">course 1 +</div>
      </td>
      <td colspan="4">
          <div id="course1" style="display: none">
              Here is the text
              <div class="close"><br/>X</div>
          </div>
      </td>
  </tr>
</table>

$(function(){
    $('.opener').click(function(){
    var divToOpen = $(this).data('toopen'); / get the id */
    $('#' + divToOpen).slideToggle(); /* this toggles it up and down so close not needed */
  });
  $('.close').click(function(){ /* but if you want close button that's ok too */
    $(this).parent().slideUp(); /* slide it back up */
  })
})
```

[Here's a fiddle to see it in action](https://jsfiddle.net/4a1mo8c5/)

Comment: I am really impressed by all these fantastic answers. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to show and hide the spoiler like this:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.show', function() {
  // gets the next td element and shows the spoiler within it
  $(this).parent().next('td').find('.spoiler').show();
});

$(document).on('click', '.hide', function() {
  // hides the spoiler
  $(this).parent('.spoiler').hide();
});
```

```css
.show {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: blue;
}
.hide {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="spoilers">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Date</td>
      <td>Place</td>
      <td>Time</td>
      <td>$</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span class="show">+</span>
      </td>
      <td colspan="4">
        <span class="spoiler" style="display:none;">
            Spoiler 1<br/> <span class="hide">X</span>
        </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span class="show">+</span>
      </td>
      <td colspan="4">
        <span class="spoiler" style="display:none;">
            Spoiler 2 <span class="hide">X</span>
        </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span class="show">+</span>
      </td>
      <td colspan="4">
        <span class="spoiler" style="display:none;">
            Spoiler 3 <span class="hide">X</span>
        </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: @buchstabe no problem :) if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a JQuery-free answer.
Generally you did it ok,
do some modification in your code:

1. instead of "open", use "do_open", same with "close".
2. delete "display: block;" from css
3. use class instead of ids and use DOM elements methods and properties such as [querySelector()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselector.asp) and [parentNode](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_parentnode.asp)

```js
function do_open(opener) {
  opener.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector('.toggling-content').style.display = 'block';

}

function do_close(opener) {
  opener.parentNode.style.display = 'none';

}
```

```css
.opener {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.closer {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Date</td>
        <td>Place</td>
        <td>Time</td>
        <td>$</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="opener" onclick="do_open(this)">+</div>
        </td>
        <td colspan="4">
          <div class='toggling-content' style="display:none;">
            Here is the text1

            <div class="closer" onclick="do_close(this)">
              <br/>X</div>

          </div>

        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="opener" onclick="do_open(this)">+</div>
        </td>
        <td colspan="4">
          <div class='toggling-content' style="display:none;">
            Here is the text1

            <div class="closer" onclick="do_close(this)">
              <br/>X</div>

          </div>

        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>

  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please read the question `The code works fine, if I tell in the JS section the "getElementById" a fixed id. But I want to have this multiple times.`

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I got much input which makes it very clear.